# React won't load DOM elements

Tags: reactjs

I setup a standard HTML page and imported react and  babel .js files in order to learn how to use the React framework.  Unfortunately, I am unable to get the following example to work.  I am not using grunt or another runner to compile the JSX code, so I imported the broswer.min.js file.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?  I am not worried about performance and I just want to use this app for learning purposes, so I would prefer not to have local runners to compile the JSX code which will add setup complications.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React Test!</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    React Test...
    <hr>

    <div id="example"></div>

    <script type="text/babel">
        ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, it works!</h1>, document.getElementById('example'));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can use https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app it's about as easy to setup as `install` and `start`

Comment: That actually works well for my goal of not installing runners and other overhead tools for this learning project.  Please post as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: `I just want to use this app for learning purposes, so I would prefer not to have local runners to compile the JSX code which will add setup complications.` This is pretty much contradictory. If you want to learn, learn the whole process, not a quarter of it. And it's really not that complicated to have a basic setup of loader/babel.

Comment: @OmriAharon It is absolutely not contradictory. I am headed in that direction, but I want to get started specifically with React and JSX.  I am still in the process of figuring out what is needed and I don't know what value babel, grunt or other tools provide, so I want to start learning React right now, without delay. As I learn, I will add more to the mix. It's completely normal.

Comment: What I mean is, you can set it up in 3-5 minutes and you don't have to worry about it again